# Write into a data.json file array

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, web-deployment

I have a `data.json` file that I need to modify from a `TS` file.

The `data.json` file looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "81a885d6-8f68-5bc0-bbbc-1c7b32e4b4e4",
        "title": "Need a Little Help with Your Site? Hire a Corvid Web Developer",
    },
    {
        "id": "36043e94-6d21-5d2a-b1eb-f983996e3d79",
        "title": "Guidelines for posting a question",
    },
]
```

Meaning it's an array of objects. In practice, there are more fields and hundreds of objects.

I have two cases in modifying the file:

1. I need to change one field of one object
2. I need to insert a new object into the array

I looked online into writing on `.json` files, and I was only able to find 'How to Override'.

It would very wasteful for me to override ALL THE FILE, just to change the field of an object, or just to add a new object.

Anyone knows how can I achieve 1,2, without having to override all the hundreds of objects?

Thanks

Comment: You can’t.  Did you try to modify a file content without overwrite it?

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is use the same approch of overriding but instead every time return the mapped over array with the changed value.

```
import FileToModify from './FileToModify.json';
import fs from 'fs';

const data = [...fileToModify].map(item => item.id === 'someId' ? 
({
  ...item,
  name: 'new Name'
}) : item );

fs.writeFile("./FileToModify.json", JSON.stringify((data)), (err) => {
  // In case of a error throw err.
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Sucess!");
});
```